# Weird behavior with st_clusterwithin

Tags: postgis, clustering

I'm not sure I'm doing this right, I've two locations, one a point and one a point within an area. I'm running them through `st_clusterwithin`, and they both create 2 individual cluster groups (which is fine). Problems start when I try to rejoin the cluster using `st_contains`. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong, or have I stumbled across a weird bug?

```
-- postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2
CREATE TABLE test (name character varying, p geometry(point, 900913), a geometry(Geometry, 900913));
INSERT INTO test values ('a', '010100002031BF0D00713D0AD7F54711C1A4703D1A3D965941', null);
INSERT INTO test values ('b', '010100002031BF0D0002FB34FAC62E11C1FAF7FB8141965941', '010300002031BF0D00010000000D0000009A9999998B3211C114AE47F13D965941295C8FC2863211C1A4703D5A569659418FC2F528D33011C1EC51B84E5A9659417B14AE47B62F11C1B81E851B5A965941295C8FC2BC2F11C18FC2F5F85D96594114AE47E10D2C11C1295C8FE26F965941EC51B81EF32B11C1666666D6699659417B14AE47D12C11C1F6285CFF139659418FC2F528BA2F11C1F6285C7F14965941B81E85EBBE2F11C11F85EB01279659415C8FC2F5DB2F11C1D7A3702D2C965941F6285C8F2F3011C15C8FC235309659419A9999998B3211C114AE47F13D965941');

select name, st_contains(ST_CollectionHomogenize(c.g), u.p)
    from test u, 
        (select unnest(st_clusterwithin(coalesce(u2.a, st_expand(u2.p, 350)), 250)) g
        from test u2) c order by name;

  name | st_contains 
------+-------------
 a    | t
 a    | f
 b    | t
 b    | t
(4 rows)
```

Notice that the temporary table below is identical to the inner select above:

```
create temporary table test_g as 
  select unnest(st_clusterwithin(coalesce(a, st_expand(p, 350)), 250)) g  
  from test;
select name, st_contains(ST_CollectionHomogenize(c.g), u.p)
    from test u, test_g c order by name;
osm_gb-#  name | st_contains 
------+-------------
 a    | f
 a    | f
 b    | t
 b    | t
(4 rows)
```

Neither of the outputs appear to be correct, I'd expect one 'a' row to be true for it's cluster and false for the other, and 'b' likewise.

Comment: Based on @dbaston's find, a quick workaround is to recreate the geometry with `ST_CollectionHomogenize(c.g)::text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there's a weird bug here, but it's actually in `ST_CollectionHomogenize`.  I filed a report here:

https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3569

As a workaround, you should be able to use `ST_CollectionExtract` instead of `ST_CollectionHomogenize` to turn your GeometryCollections into (Multi)Polygons to perform the intersection/containment test.

Comment: Thanks for filing and figuring it out! I tried to sign up to that trac but the signup process involved IRC so I took that as a 'not welcome here' sign.
Your workaround was successful with the select being `select name, ST_Contains(ST_CollectionExtract(c.g, 3), u.p)`. The `3` argument selects polygonal members of the GeometryCollection (they were all polygons in the example anyway)

Comment: This approach came about from using my own answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482754/
Maybe there is a better approach to using `ST_ClusterExtract`?

Comment: The usability problem (for this scenario) comes the fundamental limitations of an aggregate (just like you can't say "give me the max ID and the name that goes with it").  A more flexible window function will be available in 2.3; see the [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html) or an [example](https://dbaston.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/dbscan-clustering-in-postgis/) for ST_ClusterDBSCAN.  Until then, you could consider abusing the Z or M ordinates to pass an ID through to make the join less painful.